# Replace special character with its index

Tags: ruby, string

I need to replace all special characters within a string with their index. 
For example,

```
"I-need_to@change$all%special^characters^"
```

should become:

```
"I1need6to9change16all20special28characters39"
```

The index of all special character differs.
I have checked many links [replacing all with single character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705194/replace-special-characters-in-a-string-with-underscore), [occurances of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819540/return-index-of-all-occurances-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-ruby). 
I found very similar link but it I do not want to adopt these [replace its index number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329621/ruby-replace-a-character-in-a-string-with-its-index-number) as I need to replace all of the special characters.

I have also tried to do something like this:

```
str.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')
```

Here str is my example string.
As this replaces all the characters but with space, and I want the index instead of space. Either all of the special character or these seven

```
\/*[]:?
```

I need to replace this seven mainly but it would be OK if we replace all of them.

I need a simpler way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `str`? .....

Comment: str is the string ("I-need_to@change$all%special^characters^").

Answer (score 2):

You can use the global variable [`` $` ``](http://jimneath.org/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings.html#_dollar_backtick) and the block form of `gsub`:

```
irb> str = "I-need_to@change$all%special^characters^"
=> "I-need_to@change$all%special^characters^"
irb> str.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/) { $`.length }
=> "I1need6to9change16all20special28characters39"
```